# Submit WFFM via javascript ajax post without reloading the page?

Tags: wffm, webforms, ajax

I have a WFFM form on a page that has a lot of dynamic content. When the form is submitted, the page reloads (as a postback) to display the success message, which also reloads all of the content on the page and resets the state of the page for the user. I need to be able to submit the form without resetting the state of the page, so I'm trying to submit the form with an ajax post request and show a success or error message based on the response:

```
$("form").unbind().on("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this);
  var submitUrl = $(form).attr("action");
  var data = $(form).serializeAndEncode();
  var deferred = $.post(submitUrl, data);
  $("form").submit();
  deferred.success(function (e) {
    $(".sucess-message").show();
  });
  deferred.error(function (e) {
    alert("Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.");
  });
});
```

});

The javascript is hitting the `success` code, but I don't think it's actually working. The value of `e` in `deferred.success` in an HTML body that has no content in it that indicates the submit succeeded (I don't see my success message in the body), and I checked the form data in Sitecore and do not see my submission data. **It might matter that there are two forms on this page, but this was also the case for a test page where this was the only form**. Is there any way that I can submit this form with javascript without reloading the page, and determine when the form has completed submitting/if it was a success?

Comment: If you are using the MVC form controller, you can set your form to execute an ajax form submit, checking the `Is Ajax Mvc Form` form field.

Comment: That's unfortunately not possible with this site as it's webforms only